# correct antonym for individualistic

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking for an antonym for individualistic that ideologically corresponds to valuing the common good above the individual.

For example when Spock says "*the needs of the many outweighs the needs of the few*", what ideological stance could this view be ascribed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 
[collectivism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collectivism) may convey the concept you are referring to (www.merriam-webster.com):

> - emphasis on collective rather than individual action or identity
> - Any of several types of **social organization that ascribe central importance to the groups to which individuals belong** (e.g., state, nation, ethnic group, or social class). **It may be contrasted with individualism. Jean-Jacques Rousseau was the first modern philosopher to discuss it** (1762). Karl Marx was its most forceful proponent in the 19th century. Communism, fascism, and socialism may all be termed collectivist systems. See also communitarianism; kibbutz; moshav.

[Collectivistic cultures](http://psychology.about.com/od/cindex/fl/What-Are-Collectivistic-Cultures.htm): (www:psychology.about.com)

> - emphasize the needs and goals of the group as a whole over the needs and wishes of each individual. In such cultures, relationships with other members of the group and the interconnectedness between people play a central role in each person's identity. Cultures in Asia, Central America, South America, and Africa tend to be more collectivistic.

Answer (score 10):

***Collectivism*** is what you're looking for.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectivism):

> Collectivism is any philosophic, political, religious, economic, or
>   social outlook that emphasizes the interdependence of every human.
>   Collectivism is a basic cultural element that ***exists as the reverse of
>   individualism in human nature*** (in the same way high context culture
>   exists as the reverse of low context culture). Collectivist
>   orientations stress the importance of cohesion within social groups
>   (such as an "in-group", in what specific context it is defined) and in
>   some cases, the priority of group goals over individual goals.
>   Collectivists often focus on community, society, nation or country. It
>   has been used as an element in many different and diverse types of
>   government and political, economic and educational philosophies
>   throughout history and most human societies in practice contain
>   elements of both individualism and collectivism. Some examples of
>   collectivist cultures include Pakistan, India and Japan

Comment: I realize you probably wrote your answer concurrently with Josh61, but in the end I had to pick one accepted answer, and since Josh61's answer was published a few minutes before yours I went for that one. Thanks a lot for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Moralistic or collective society

Source:
http://www.wtamu.edu/~jrausch/polcul.html

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think it's *better* than the other answer (collectivism), another word you might consider is socialist/socialism. Unfortunately it has a lot of polarizing political connotations (which vary widely from place to place) that increase your risk of being misunderstood, but there are certainly audiences where socialism would have a more positive connotation than collectivism.

The wikipedia disambiguation page is informative and might have other useful ideas for wording for related concepts:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialism_(disambiguation)